# Sending value from java to javascript using JavaScriptInterface

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Android App has:

```
JavaScriptNFCInterface NFCIDConnector = new JavaScriptNFCInterface(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(NFCIDConnector, "Android");

public class JavaScriptNFCInterface {
    public JavaScriptNFCInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public String getNFCID() {
            return NFCID;
        }

}
```

And for testing purpose in UI:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onclick="console.log(Android.getNFCID)" role="button">test</a>
```

but im receiving only:

```
chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "function () { [native code] }", source: http://192.168.173.216:8082/#/tablet/index (1)
```

not string with ID.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses after the function name, so instead of calling it, you are just printing it. You need to replace:

```
console.log(Android.getNFCID)
```

with:

```
console.log(Android.getNFCID())
```